# como hago cuenta regresiva en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

necesito que si a los 5 min de inactividad se redirija una web a google tengo el siguiente script

```
funtion time(){
     tiempo_resta:500seg;
     location.replace("https://www.GOOGLE.com");
}
```

seria algo como de html esto lo que necesito pero en JS

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="500; url=http://www.google.com/">
```

Pregunto como se hace en JS?

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que utilizar el método `setTimeout()` para que cuando transcurra un periodo de tiempo, se abrirá una nueva pestaña (por el `_blank`) redirigiendo a la URL:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var windowOpen = window.open("https://google.com.pe","_blank");
}, 300000);
```

por ejemplo:

```js
setTimeout(function redirect() {
  window.open("https://www.google.com/","_blank");
}, 1000); // sería 300000 para los 5 minutos
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Por alguna extraña razón, los snippets de SO no permite mostrar el `window.open`, te adjunto [un enlace](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/rNKRRMj) para que veas como funciona.

Comment: No sería mejor usar un `windows.location = "http://google.com"`... window .open no abre es una nueva ventana/pestaña? lo que el OP quiere es redirigir a otra url

Comment: De todas formas te redirecciona a otra URL, la única diferencia es que abre una nueva ventana, y lo veo mejor así.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me parece mejor setear el `location`, para así lograr una redirección de la página actual. Sería así:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";
}, 30000);
```

Saludos